# How to define tokens in spaCy NLP in Python?

Tags: python, ios, web-applications, nlp

I want to use spaCy features of NLP in my FlaskApp. I have been search different examples on official sites: (for spaCy)
https://spacy.io/docs/usage/tutorials

and (for Flask)
https://realpython.com/blog/python/flask-by-example-part-3-text-processing-with-requests-beautifulsoup-nltk/

In MyWebapp I have code to post a result of NLP analysis from `parse_news_from`:

```
@app.route('/submit', methods=['POST'])
def submit_textarea():
    if(parse_news_from(format(request.form["text"]))):
       print("The news is parsed sucessfully!");
    return talk_title;
```

Currently `parse_news_from` works with NLTK library, but I am going to use spaCy.
Here is my code for spaCy from official sources:

```
from spacy.en import English
import _regex
parser = English()

# Test Data
multiSentence = "There is an art, it says, or rather, a knack to flying." \
                 "The knack lies in learning how to throw yourself at the ground and miss." \
                 "In the beginning the Universe was created. This has made a lot of people "\
                 "very angry and been widely regarded as a bad move."
# all you have to do to parse text is this:
#note: the first time you run spaCy in a file it takes a little while to load up its modules
parsedData = parser(multiSentence)

# Let's look at the tokens
# All you have to do is iterate through the parsedData
# Each token is an object with lots of different properties
# A property with an underscore at the end returns the string representation
# while a property without the underscore returns an index (int) into spaCy's vocabulary
# The probability estimate is based on counts from a 3 billion word
# corpus, smoothed using the Simple Good-Turing method.
for i, token in enumerate(parsedData):
    print("original:", token.orth, token.orth_)
    print("lowercased:", token.lower, token.lower_)
    print("lemma:", token.lemma, token.lemma_)
    print("shape:", token.shape, token.shape_)
    print("prefix:", token.prefix, token.prefix_)
    print("suffix:", token.suffix, token.suffix_)
    print("log probability:", token.prob)
    print("Brown cluster id:", token.cluster)
    print("----------------------------------------")
    if i > 1:
        break
```

After execution I have a mistake:

```
File "/home/xxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_regex_core.py", line 21, in <module>
    import _regex
ImportError: /home/xxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_regex.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: PySlice_AdjustIndices
```

Are there any working examples how to do it for starting? Where my mistake? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem with the aforementioned mistake and it's so unpredictable for me. It's described here:
[How to fix a python spaCy error: "undefined symbol: PySlice_AdjustIndices"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44095147/how-to-fix-a-python-spacy-error-undefined-symbol-pyslice-adjustindices)