# How to fix a python spaCy error: "undefined symbol: PySlice_AdjustIndices"?

Tags: python, spacy

Using official example from [here](https://nicschrading.com/project/Intro-to-NLP-with-spaCy/) I have a mistake:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vv/PythProj/esi-code/webapp/sp_token.py", line 2, in <module>
    from spacy.en import English
  File "/home/vv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import util
  File "/home/vv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 5, in <module>
    import regex as re
  File "/home/vv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/regex.py", line 394, in <module>
    import _regex_core
  File "/home/vv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_regex_core.py", line 21, in <module>
    import _regex
ImportError: /home/vv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_regex.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: PySlice_AdjustIndices
```

How can I fix it? Thank you for help
Additional information:
for command:  `conda search "^python$"`

```
Fetching package metadata .........
python        1.0.1                         0  conda-forge     
              1.0.1                         0  defaults        
                  ... // closely 50 tuples
              3.6.1                         0  defaults        
              3.6.1                         1  conda-forge     
              3.6.1                         2  conda-forge     
              3.6.1                         2  defaults
```

for command:

```
python --version
Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)
```

for command:

```
pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /home/vv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
```

Comment: Did you deliberately choose to use anaconda? If not start from a clean virtualenv. It would be also useful, if you edit your question with the OS version and the output of `python --version` and `pip --version`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot explain it, but it works when I run `idle3` under `sudo`:

I use Python shell and run it from terminal by command: `idle3`. Later when I compile the code I get the aforementioned mistake.

but: when I start from terminal: `sudo idle3` it works perfect without any mistakes. So, I think it's a question from access in ubuntu.

Thank you for all!